# Two bodies that collided inelastically and rebounded

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

[image]

I can't find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the kinetic energy before the collision was $\frac 1 2 (25m_1 + 16m_2)$ and after the collision it is $\frac 1 2 (9m_1+4m_2)$. The difference is $480$ joules, so you have

$8m_1 + 6m_2 = 480$

Also, conservation of momentum tells you that $5m_1 - 4m_2 = 2m_2 - 3m_1$ which you can rearrange to give

$8m_1 = 6m_2$

From these two equations you can find the values of $m_1$ and $m_2$.